# ./watch is compiling the JS library files mostly but one file it is always caching

Tags: asp.net, ember.js

I am using Ember even though I am making changes but when I run the ./watch its not producing the JavaScript file with new code - its annoying - I am making the manual change but that's not correct solution right? I made the change to the file even by opening in folder and manually updated the code on ember file - still its writing the old code in app.js file.

What could be the reason? I am using Web Pack to run ./watch and generate the app.js file.

Here is my Ember js code:

```
export default () => { 
 IMS.registerController("case.details.assignedinspector.edit", {

    caseDetails: Ember.inject.controller('caseDetails'),
    caseId: Ember.computed.alias('caseDetails.model.imscase.id'),
    clearForm: function () {
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    },
    actions: {
        close: function (id) {
            $('.modal').modal('hide');
            this.transitionToRoute('case.details');
        },

        async save() {
            var scope = this;

            //validating form
            if ($("#edit-assignedinspector-form").validate()) {
                var data = {                    
                    AssignedToInvestigators: Ember.get(scope, 'model.imscase.assignedToInvestigators'), //AssignedToInspectorId: $("#assignedInspectorSelect").chosen().val(),
                    CaseId: this.get('caseId')
                };
                try {
                    let response = await this.api('Case/UpdateAssignedInvestigators').post(data);
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');
                    toastr.success("Assigned Inspector Edit Saved.");
                    scope.transitionToRoute("case.details");
                    scope.get('caseDetails').refreshData();
                    scope.clearForm();
                } catch (ex) {
                    toastr.error("Error saving Assigned Inspector.");
                }
            }
            else {
                toastr.warning("Please fix the form", "Validation failed");
            }
        },
        didInsert: function () {
            $('#edit-assignedinspector-modal').modal();
        }
    }
}); 
 }
```

Here is how its generating the old code in app.js file:

```
  save: function () {
    var _save = _asyncToGenerator(
    /*#__PURE__*/
    regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
      var scope, data, response;
      return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
        while (1) {
          switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
            case 0:
              scope = this; //validating form

              if (!$("#edit-assignedinspector-form").validate()) {
                _context.next = 19;
                break;
              }

              data = {
                AssignedToInspectorId: $("#assignedInspectorSelect").chosen().val(),
                CaseId: this.get('caseId')
              };
              _context.prev = 3;
              _context.next = 6;
              return this.api('Case/UpdateAssignedInspector').post(data);

            case 6:
              response = _context.sent;
              $('.modal').modal('hide');
              toastr.success("Assigned Inspector Edit Saved.");
              scope.transitionToRoute("case.details");
              scope.get('caseDetails').refreshData();
              scope.clearForm();
              _context.next = 17;
              break;

            case 14:
              _context.prev = 14;
              _context.t0 = _context["catch"](3);
              toastr.error("Error saving Assigned Inspector.");

            case 17:
              _context.next = 20;
              break;

            case 19:
              toastr.warning("Please fix the form", "Validation failed");

            case 20:
            case "end":
              return _context.stop();
          }
        }
      }, _callee, this, [[3, 14]]);
    }));

    function save() {
      return _save.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    return save;
  }()
```

It is supposed to call Case/UpdateAssignedInvestigators instead its still calling the Case/UpdateAssignedInspector, which is incorrect.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sorry I put it mistakenly my apologies

Comment: its unclear how you're compiling your js. Are you using `ember-cli`? whats your ember version?

Comment: My Ember version is: "3.14.1", but how can I know whether that I am using ember-cli or something else?